# My pc can only work on ethernet, don't know how to activate the wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, hp-pavilion

I have an [HP Pavilion 20 All-in-One PC](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03524659-160) running with Win 8. I recently moved from the place I was living and cannot manage to establish a connection. In my old place the computer connected through ethernet and worked perfectly. In my new house I cannot connect it through an ethernet cable because the PC is upstairs while the modem is downstairs. I wanted to conmect it through Wifi but it seems that the PC has no Wifi option. I know that is not possible because I have seen the same computer with Wifi connections before. I tried going to the adapter settings in Network and Sharing Center but apparently the only option available is through an ethernet cable. What do I have to do?

Comment: is your hardware wifi button enabled?

Comment: Does the HP Pavilion 20 even have a 802.11 device to connect to a 802.11 network?

Comment: The HP Pav 20 and 20z's I've pulled up on google all have 802.11b/g/n.

Comment: Does the modem have wireless capability? Has the wireless network been activated? If so, maybe it's hidden which will require you to know the SSID and password.

Answer (score 3):

Your Wifi driver might not be properly installed **if you press your Wifi button** and the card still does not "wake up".

To correct this issue, if the card is not automatically recognised and drivers found, the possible solution is to enter control panel and procceed as follows:

[image]

1 -  Find the card and do as specified on image

[image]

2 - Click the hardware ID, <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> it, then paste on google to find the apropriate drivers. note: always prefer manufacturer websites for this.